# How to set Trigger from parent property to set child property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, datatrigger

I keep going around in circles on this data trigger so it is not working...

I have a button that has a border for a default dropshadow. However, I want to create a dep property to be used to toggle this. Yet, I never get to the point where the effect is being set.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Template">
 <Setter.Value>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrls:RoundedButton">
   <Grid>
    <Border>
     <Border.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ctrls:RoundedButton">
       <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsDropShadowVisible" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Effect">
          <Setter.Value>
           <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1"/>
          </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
        </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
     </Border.Style>
```

This is based off of a button, but is implemented as the custom user control...This is legacy code...

Comment: Post the full XAML. Also, that `DataTrigger` doesn't make sense. Use a regular `Trigger Property=IsDropShadowVisible.. etc..`.

Comment: Your XAML doesn't make sense. You have a `Style TargetType="Button"` and then a `ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrls:RoundedButton"`. I suggest you look at [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net) for introductory XAML stuff.

Comment: @HighCore yah....I just added a note to that...I am trying to fix that, but it is embedded elsewhere and is causing issues...is there any way to do this otherwise? Or do I need to fix this legacy stuff

Comment: legacy? I don't think that means what you think that means.

Comment: Dude your XAML is completely wrong. On top of that you have a `Border` with a `Style TargetType="RoundedButton"`??? Post a screenshot of what you need and I can give you some proper XAML.

Comment: I think you (or whoever wrote this XAML) have a BIG misconception of WPF Styles.

Comment: @LeeLouviere Technically, legacy could be considered anything that has been committed to source. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_code Just because it is WPF, does not mean it can't be legacy

Comment: @HighCore I entirely agree, however I was trying to wiggle in what I could for what should be a simple feature request without having to rewrite it....

Comment: @JustinPihony I hear you. I often find myself having to refactor the entire application due to crappy winforms-mentality code. I realized I lose less time redoing it all myself than having to deal with these kind of things. WPF is not for beginners, that might be the reason why a lot of people prefer winforms.

Comment: I suggest you fully remove that style and start all over yourself.

Comment: @JustinPihony Just remove the border style, name the border, then give the setter that targetname. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have here works
Did this in a new WPF window. No other code-behind than what you see here.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ShadowButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ShadowButton}">
                    <Button Name="Button"></Button>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDropShadowVisible" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Effect">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- snip code -->

<local:ShadowButton Height="10" Width="10" IsDropShadowVisible="true"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class ShadowButton : Button
{
    public DependencyProperty IsDropShadowVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsDropShadowVisible", typeof(Boolean), typeof(ShadowButton), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    public Boolean IsDropShadowVisible
    {
        get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IsDropShadowVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDropShadowVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you take into account this comment, then this fixed my problem: Just remove the border style, name the border, then give the setter that targetname. Done.